# error with multiprocessing parsed data to sqlite

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, sqlite, multiprocessing

I am trying to parse a bunch of links and append the parsed data to sqlite3. I am getting errors that the sqlite3 database is locked, so maybe it's because I am using too high a pool value? I tried to lower it to 5 but I am still getting errors shown below.

My code is basically looking like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(parse_link, links)
```

My real code is looking like this:

```
with Pool(5) as p:
    p.map(Get_FT_OU, file_to_set('links.txt'))
    # Where Get_FT_OU(link) appends links to a sqlite3 database.
```

When the code runs I often get these errors. Can someone help me to fix it?

```
    multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "/Users/christian/Documents/GitHub/odds/CP_Parser.py", line 166, in Get_FT_OU
    cursor.execute(sql_str)
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/christian/Documents/GitHub/odds/CP_Parser.py", line 206, in <module>
    p.map(Get_FT_OU, file_to_set('links.txt'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 266, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked
>>>
```

I can run the code fine without using multiprocessing and actually also while using Pool(2) I get no errors, but if I go higher I get these errors. I'm using the newest MacBook Air.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It somehow worked by adding a timeout=10 to the connection

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(DB_FILENAME, timeout=10)
```